# Making AngularUI UI-Date datepicker use UTC time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

It seems the datepicker uses localized time but I need it to use UTC times when I make calls to the backend. I get around this issue by adjusting the value before posting it to the server using the following function:

```
function adjustDateForTimeOffset(dateToAdjust) {
    var offsetMs = dateToAdjust.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    return new Date(dateToAdjust.getTime() - offsetMs);
}
```

or simply by wrangling my date in a service. However, I also have some defaults that I want to use on load in my application and I need these dates to be in UTC and be displayed in the datepicker input box. However when I do this, the date is always a day before in the input box because ui-date uses local time.

Is there a way to modify ui-date to run on UTC time all the time instead of local time?

I've searched around the internet for an answer to this question but just keep finding ways to modify the date-ui but just keep finding ways to change the date before sending it to the server but that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

javascript's date object always uses the local timezone regardless.

As soon as you create a date object, regardless of the input date, it will be shown using the local timezone offset.

You don't say how you're sending your dates to your server, but I assume you're just sending a date string?

In that case you could use the `Date.prototype.toISOString()` method as this will give you an ISO standard date string, which means it is in UTC.

i.e.

```
// this lets you convert a specific UTC date into a standard local date
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(......));

// send to server
$http.post('url', { date: date.toISOString() });
```

more info, see:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp
and
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

Comment: Yes, I have got that working using toISOString...but the problem, is when I have defaults in UTC time and need to fill in the input boxes for the datepicker which is in localtime.

Comment: The other option is create your dates as if local time is utc. So you do ``new Date(1970,0,1,0,0,0).addSeconds(timestamp)``